# Empty object given : laravel 5.1 ajax file upload

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, file-upload

**HTML form**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'events.store','id'=>'form-create-event','name' => 'form-create-event','files'=>true]) !!}
<div class="card">

    <div class="card-body card-padding">

        <div class="row">
            <div id="step1" class="col-sm-4">
                <!-- <h3 class="c-gray m-b-15">principales information</h3> -->
                <div class="round round-lg blue">
                    <span>1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <p class="f-200 m-b-5 c-gray">Type d'évènement</p>
                        <select id="type_event" name="type_event" class="tag-select" data-placeholder="">
                            @foreach($types_events as $value)
                            <option value="{!! $value->id !!}">
                                {{$value->name}}
                            </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control fg-input" data-rule-minlength='2' required="false" id="event_name" name="event_name">
                    </div>
                    <label class="fg-label">Nom de l'évènement</label>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="form-group fg-float">
              <div class="fg-line">
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control fg-input input-mask" required="true" data-mask="0000-00-00" name="event_begin_date" id="event_begin_date">
              </div>
              <label class="fg-label">Date début (expl 2016-01-30)</label>
              </div> -->
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="md md-event"></i></span>
                    <div class="dtp-container dropdown fg-line">
                        <input type='text' name="event_begin_date" id="event_begin_date" class="form-control date-picker" data-toggle="dropdown" placeholder="Date début">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="form-group fg-float">
              <div class="fg-line">
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control fg-input input-mask"  required="false" data-mask="0000-00-00" id="event_end_date" name="event_end_date">
              </div>
              <label class="fg-label">Date fin (expl 2016-01-31)</label>
              </div> -->
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="md md-event"></i></span>
                    <div class="dtp-container dropdown fg-line">
                        <input type='text' id="event_end_date" name="event_end_date" class="form-control date-picker" data-toggle="dropdown" placeholder="Date fin">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group fg-float'>
                    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file m-r-10">
                <span class="fileinput-new">Ajouter un document</span>
                        <span class="fileinput-exists">Modifier</span>
                        <input type="file" id="event_document" name="event_document">
                        </span>
                        <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
                        <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" id="cancelFileUpload" data-dismiss="fileinput">&times;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- <div id="event_document_tag_name" class="form-group">

                <input type="text" placeholder="Tag" id="event_document_tag" name="event_document_tag" class="form-control">

            </div> -->

                <div class="form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <textarea name="event_description" id="event_description" required="false" class="form-control">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <label class="fg-label">Description</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <textarea id="event_info_pr" name="event_info_pr" required="false" class="form-control">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <label class="fg-label">Informations pratiques</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <textarea name="event_adress" required="false" id="event_adress" class="form-control">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <label class="fg-label">Adresse</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="step2" class="col-sm-4">
                <!-- <h3 class="c-gray m-b-15">informations</h3> -->
                <div class="round round-lg blue">
                    <span>2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <p class="f-200 m-b-5 c-gray">Invités
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modalDefaultUploadUsers" class="btn btn-success btn-xs waves-effect pull-right">
                                <i class="md md-file-upload"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a style="margin-right: 10px;" data-toggle="modal" href="#modalDefaultAddUser" class="btn btn-success btn-xs waves-effect pull-right">
                                <i class="md md-add"></i>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                        <select multiple id="event_publics" name="event_publics[]" class="tag-select" data-placeholder="">
                            @foreach($users as $value)
                            <option value="{!! $value->id !!}">
                                {{$value->firstname}} {{$value->lastname}}
                            </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <p class="f-200 m-b-5 c-gray">Intervenants
                        </p>
                        <select id="event_speakers" name="speakers[]" class="tag-select" multiple data-placeholder="">
                            @foreach($users as $value)
                            <option value="{!! $value->id !!}">
                                {{$value->firstname}} {{$value->lastname}}
                            </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Groupe et participants -->
                <div class="form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        <p class="f-200 m-b-5 c-gray">Groupes et participants</p>
                        <!-- <select id="event_gp_participants" name="gps_participants[]" class="demo" multiple="multiple">
                  @foreach($groups as $group)
                  @if($group->id !== 1 && $group->id !== 2)
                  <optgroup value="{{$group->id}}" label="{{$group->name}} ">
                    @foreach($users as $value)
                    <option value="group[{{$group->id}}][{{$value->id}}]" >
                      {{$value->firstname}} {{$value->lastname}}
                    </option>
                    @endforeach
                  </optgroup>
                  @endif
                  @endforeach
                  </select> -->
                        <select id="event_gp_participants" data-live-search="true" name="gps_participants[]" multiple class="selectpicker">
                            @foreach($groups as $group) @if($group->id !== 1 && $group->id !== 2)
                            <optgroup value="{{$group->id}}" label="{{$group->name}} ">
                                @foreach($users as $value)
                                <option value="group[{{$group->id}}][{{$value->id}}]">
                                    {{$value->firstname}} {{$value->lastname}}
                                </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </optgroup>
                            @endif @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="step3" class="col-sm-4">
                <!-- <h3 class="c-gray m-b-15">informations</h3> -->
                <div class="round round-lg blue">
                    <span>3</span>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="data-table-basic" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="3">
                                    <a class="pull-right" data-toggle="modal" href="#modalWider">
                      Ajouter séance
                      </a>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> Enregistrer
        </button>
        {!! link_to_route('events.index', 'Annuler', [], ['class' => 'btn btn-link']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**JS code**

```
var form = document.forms.namedItem("form-create-event");
console.log(form);
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    oData = new FormData(form);
    oData.append("seances", seance);
    console.log(oData);
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", form.action, true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        if (oReq.status == 200) {
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    };
    oReq.send(oData);
    ev.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

**PHP code**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json( $request->all());
}
```

---

The Problem : `dd($request->event_document)` returns empty object

[header request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7dyZ.png)

[Server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxsBt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are trying to upload files bigger than in size allowed by your php.ini. so set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

upload_max_filesize = 10M or whatever size you need

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize

post_max_size = 10M

Comment: Thank you Ravisha Hesh,   well i simply add this condition if($request->file('event_document')->isValid()){ }     and it works fine !